# Issue with text exceeding the container (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

as you can see on [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdta5v3q/), if you play with the window size, the lorem ipsum text sometimes goes outside the white container. 
I can't figure out why, because when I look at the code, everything seems to be embedded within the main container so I would expect the text to adapt the fluidly adapt to the window size.
What is the issue?
Thanks,

```
<section>
            <div class="container content">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 bordering">
                  <h2>Qui <b>sommes-nous?</b></h2>
                  <h3>Actifs depuis </h3></div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                  <div class="title-block">
                    <p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, connecteur adipiscin
 <p>
etc.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have applied a fixed width to `.container`:

```
.container {
    width: 1260px; /* remove or edit this line */
}
```